# Why does "merk" mean "meld"? Is it Japanese, or Hymmnos, or something else?

Tags: ar-tonelico

Why does "merk" mean "meld"? Is it Japanese, Hymmnos, or something else?

According to the EXA_PICO Universe Wiki's [Grathmeld](https://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/Grathmeld) article, in the original Japanese, it's グラスメルク, or "Glassmerk"?

Ar tonelico Qoga: Knell of Ar Ciel Original Soundtrack Disc 2: Song 24 is originally titled as [Merk~Tilia](http://www.team-e.co.jp/kdsd-10044/) in English letters, which makes me think it's Hymmnos. A translation is [Meld~Tilia](https://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/Ar_tonelico_Qoga:_Knell_of_Ar_Ciel_Original_Soundtrack).

I haven't seen any "merk" entry in any Hymmnos vocabulary list, so I'm not sure what language "merk" is from.

Although, I suppose it could be a distortion of "make" or something, if it is Hymmnos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the German word Merck, and it's just the shorthand variation for Glassmerk. So it's just a made-up term that is not in Japanese or any of the conlangs made for the series.

First, Merk is the official romanization Gust gave to メルク, and the only relationship there seems to be is the name of a pharmaceutical company and Gust's liking for German-sounding names. So they just grabbed that as what they thought most convenient as the name for a synthesis system for their made-up world.